# How do I express x in terms of y in this set of equations?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, systems-of-equations

The first equation is

$$a=\sqrt{\left(\cos\left(g\right)\sqrt{y\left(b-d\right)^2+y\left(a-c\right)^2}+\left(c-\frac{1}{x}\right)\cos\left(-xd\right)\right)^2+\left(\sin\left(g\right)\sqrt{y\left(b-d\right)^2+y\left(a-c\right)^2}+\left(c-\frac{1}{x}\right)\sin\left(-xd\right)\right)^2}+\frac{1}{x}$$

The second equation is

$$b=\arctan\left(\frac{\sin\left(g\right)\sqrt{y\left(b-d\right)^2+y\left(a-c\right)^2}+\left(c-\frac{1}{x}\right)\sin\left(-xd\right)}{\cos\left(g\right)\sqrt{y\left(b-d\right)^2+y\left(a-c\right)^2}+\left(c-\frac{1}{x}\right)\cos\left(-xd\right)}\right)$$

For each variable its value is the same in both equations.

How do I express x in terms of y for this set of equations?

Comment: What makes you think this can be done?

Comment: If you ever find yourself in a position where you're asked to do this, I'd suggest packing your bags to head off to a desert island.